# How to store a flag in a cookie where the flag is true only if a form has been completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

How to store a flag in a cookie where the flag is true only if a form has been completed?

I have a sidebar contains a form, which when successfully submitted fades the form and display a message using one of the user inputs.

This sidebar form is present over a number of pages on the website. In order to identify if the form has already been completed on another page I believe I can use a flag variable to define whether this is true or false and then display the form or the message depending on the stored value.

I have never used cookies as a medium to store a value and do not know the correct syntax for them. Can I simply make the cookie when the formsubmit is successful. And on every page have a script in the header that will then be read to either display the form or not.

Is this the best way to go about this? And what is the format and correct syntax to identify something like this?

**HTML**

```
<div id="sidebarf">
<form id="sidebarform" onsubmit="return false" method="post" name="myForm" autocomplete="off" >
    <input type="text" name="name" id="username" placeholder="Name (eg. Rob James)" value="" required><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="location" id="userlocation" placeholder="Location (eg. Wacol)" value="" required><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="postcode" id="userpc" pattern="[0-9]{4}" placeholder="Postcode (eg. 4076)" maxlength="4" value="" required> <br><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="useremail" placeholder="Email Address (eg. someone@yourdomain.com" value="" required> <br><br>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" id="userphone" placeholder="Phone Number (eg. 0412345678)" maxlength="10" minlength="6" value="" required> <br><br>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="20" id="usercomment" placeholder="Comment/Question" value="" required></textarea><br><br>

    <input type="submit" id="sidebarformsubmit" value="Submit">
 </form> 
 </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("#sidebarform").on("submit", function() {
    if ($("#username").val() == "") {
        return false;


}

$("#sidebarform").fadeOut("slow", function(){
      $("#sidebarf").html("Thankyou for your inquiry " + $("#username").val() + ". We will call or email you with further details within 3 business days." );
});

return false; 

/////////////////Is this the flag?/Correct Location?//////////////
//////var completed = true 
//////document.cookie=completed;
///////////

});
</script>
```

And then would I call something like this when the page loads?

```
///////////////////DOES NOT WORK/////////////////
 <script>
   function checkCookie()
 {
 var display=getCookie("completed");
if (complete!="true")
  {
  $("#sidebarf").html("Thankyou for your inquiry " + $("#username").val() + ". We will call or email you with further details within 3 business days." );
  }
else
  {
  $("#sidebarf").html //(Don't know what to put here!)
  }
}
```

I also have this for a custom validity after the above code. But this shouldn't play a role.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#username').on({
       invalid: function (e) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity("");
        if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("Please enter a name.");
         }
        },
         input: function(e) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity("");
       }
    });
```

As I said, I honestly have no idea about the cookie use so the code is just what I've search on the web.

Comment: How much of your code is working or what is not working as you want it to? May we see your form HTML.

Comment: @user3558931 Updated Post with HTML

Comment: Added a demo below that may help you visualize how this all works together. Once your submit the form, click run to simulate a page reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [this jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) you can simplify your code a great deal. The following code should check for the cookie when the page loads. If the cookie is found, the form is immediately hidden without animation. Otherwise when the form is submitted, the cookie is set so that at the next page load the form will be hidden.

```
$(function() {
    var completed = $.cookie( 'completed' ),
        form = $('#sidebarform'),
        msg = $('#sidebarf');
    if( ( completed != undefined ) && ( completed == 'done' ) ) {
        form.hide();
        msg.html( 'Form already completed.' );
    }
    form.on("submit", function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ( $("#username").val() == "" ) {
            return false;
        }

        $(this).fadeOut("slow", function() {
            msg.html("Thank you for your inquiry " + $("#username").val() + ". We will call or email you with further details within 3 business days." );
            form.submit();
            //or submit form via ajax ---> YOUR CHOICE
            $.cookie( 'completed', 'done' );
        });
    });
});
```

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/Erh4A/1/)